# Как мне зациклить эту часть кода?

Tags: python

Как мне зациклить эту часть кода?

```
image = 'image1.jpg'
random_number = random.randint(1, 3)
if random_number == 1:
    image = 'image2.jpg'
elif random_number == 2:
    image = 'image3.jpg'
elif random_number == 3:
    image = 'image1.jpg'
```

Comment: `image = random.choice(['image2.png', 'image3.png', 'image1.png'])`

Comment: А вообще что вы имеете в виду под словом «зациклить»? Весь код можно завернуть в какой-нибудь `while True:` но что-то мне подсказывает, что вы имели в виду не совсем это

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, подробнее объяснить желаемый результат выполнения кода?

Comment: мне нужно что бы этот код повторялся всегда

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/189027

Comment: Поместить код в цикл)

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы этот код повторялся всегда - поместите его в infinite loop(бесконечный цикл):
Также я немного упростил Ваш код, но вы можете помести в цикл While и свою версию:

```
while True:
    random_number = random.randint(1,3)
    image = f"image{random_number}.jpg"
```

Comment: Хороший вариант, но у него там если число равно 3, то подставляется 1.   Не знаю, может, это он опечатался. Я думаю, ему стоит переименовать изображения так, чтобы они совпадали с цифрами. Если это возможно. Тогда ваш вариант отлично впишется

Answer (score 1):

Как и предложили в комментариях - просто завернуть в цикл `while`

```
while True: 
    random_number = random.randint(1, 3)
        if random_number == 1:
            image = 'image2.jpg'
        elif random_number == 2:
            image = 'image3.jpg'
        elif random_number == 3:
            image = 'image1.jpg'
```